# ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature from EnhancerBySpringCGLIB

Tags: java, spring, cglib, classformaterror

I"m really stumped here. I've upgraded our Spring libraries from 4.0.6 to 4.3.2. One of our tests fail when running with 4.3.2. This is the code in question:

```
@Bean(name = SCHEDULER_FACTORY)
public SchedulerFactoryBean getSchedulerFactory()
{
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    schedulerFactory.setConfigLocation(schedulerConfig);
    schedulerFactory.setResourceLoader(null);
    schedulerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(getSchedulerJobFactory());
    schedulerFactory.setAutoStartup(false);

    return schedulerFactory;
}

@Bean(name = SCHEDULER)
public Scheduler getScheduler()
{
    return getSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
}
```

I'm getting the error `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bee87fe8$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bb26669`.

Running the test using spring 4.0.6 framework works perfectly fine, but with 4.3.2, it's failing. When using 4.0.6, I was using cglib no dependencies library. With 4.3.2, the tests fail regardless of whether or not I use cglib.

Spring embeds cglib and objensis into 4.3.* core library. "Furthermore, Spring Framework 4.3 embeds the updated ASM 5.1, CGLIB 3.2.4, and Objenesis 2.4 in spring-core.jar." [SpringDocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_support_for_new_library_and_server_generations)

We were using Java 8 and cglib-no-dep 2.2 with Spring framework 4.0.6. We tried running this code with and without the standalone library and see the same results.

Stack trace:

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.quartz.Scheduler]: Factory method 'getScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  >null
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver$3.run(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
           ... 112 more
  Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  >null
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:345)
           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
  Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 188.486 sec
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337)
           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.enhanceFactoryBean(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:452)
           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:338)
           at com.example.SpringConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54d3cb35.getSchedulerFactory(<generated>)
           at com.example.SpringConfiguration.getScheduler(SpringConfiguration.java:242)
           at com.example.SpringConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54d3cb35.CGLIB$getScheduler$24(<generated>)
           at com.example.SpringConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54d3cb35$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a2a6e004.invoke(<generated>)
           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
           at com.example.SpringConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54d3cb35.getScheduler(<generated>)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
           ... 115 more
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:413)
           at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
           ... 140 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bee87fe8$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bb26669
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
           ... 145 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definetly a bug in cglib. It seems like it does not currectly determines a method in the type hierarchy to be equal to another method. Are you using Java 8 in combination with default methods in interfaces?

Cglib is not really tested for modern Java versions and experiences only little maintenance. Newer features sometimes cause trouble when using the library.

Comment: Spring embeds cglib and objensis into 4.3.* core library. 

"Furthermore, Spring Framework 4.3 embeds the updated ASM 5.1, CGLIB 3.2.4, and Objenesis 2.4 in spring-core.jar." http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_support_for_new_library_and_server_generations

We were using Java 8 and cglib-no-dep 2.2 with Spring framework 4.0.6. We tried running this code with and without the standalone library and see the same results.

What makes you so sure it's a problem with CGLIB and not Spring?

Comment: Because a `ClassFormatError` is *thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and determines that the file is malformed or otherwise cannot be interpreted as a class file*. Out of the named libraries, only cglib generates runtime jar files.